# How to validate dynamically bound drop down in aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

My HTML code

```html
<select value.bind="selectedValue & validate">
  <option value="0">Add Location Type</option>
  <option repeat.for="item of listOfValuesFromDB" model.bind="item.TeamLocationTypeId">${item.Name}</option>
</select>
```

My VM has

```
ValidationRules.ensure('selectedValue').inclusion({ within: [1, 2, 3], fullMessages: true, message: 'Please select an Item' });
```

Suppose, if i select within [1,2,3] from the dropdown list, it just works fine by no throwing any validation. But since the list has growing dynamic data, it will throw error if i select anything else apart from 1,2,3.

I am new to Aurelia framework. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to ensure that the user selects an item other than "0", you could use the following validation code:

```
ValidationRules.ensure('selectedValue').required();
```

And remove `value="0"` from your default `option` tag.

Comment: I removed value="0" from option tag, instead of inclusion, I used required. It did not validate. I set value = "", It started working. Thanks for your solution.